# How to Change Size of Images in View when Populated by ObservableCollection

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8

I have a list of images that is being populated by an ObservableCollection. This is done by binding the ItemsSource of the ListBox to the Collection in the code behind. Everything is working properly, although the list of images that results does not look pretty. Currently the images are being wrapped in a horizontal WrapPanel, which is the functionality I would like to keep. The problem though is that depending on whether the image was taken from CameraCaptureTask is landscape or portrait mode, it is either very wide or tall when presented in the view. I would like to be able to resize these images while keeping the aspect ratio in tact. Perhaps setting a limit on either the width or height being no more than 128. How exactly would I do this in the following code? Also, would the image know to keep the aspect ratio? For instance, would a portrait image know to have a max height of 128 while maintaining a width of something less than 128 to keep the aspect ratio?

MainPage.xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="Recent" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="8"
                     SelectionChanged="recent_SelectionChanged" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: lots of Question in one question..i only have suggetion for you..look you can define itemTemplate for listview and can bind its size to some properties that would be defined in your item class..of your collection of item. this is how you can manipulate the size of your image item actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your `ItemTemplate` like @tanuj_loop suggests but I would suggest potentially also embedding the item in a `ViewBox` and applying your size changes to it instead of directly to the image to ensure you retain the resolution of the image but get the size constraints you're after, so something like;

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
    <ViewBox MaxHeight="128" MaxWidth="128">
            <Image Source="{Binding }"/>
        </ViewBox>                                    
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This way your `ViewBox` handles all your potential resizing issues for you, and your images still come out as crisp as you wanted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will certainly have to try this. Also, if I wished to 'crop' the image so that the center was displayed, and cut out either the extra width or height depending on the aspect ratio for this situation, how would I modify the ViewBox parameters for that instance?

Comment: I don't think ViewBox is going to help you much for cropping, you'll want to look at WriteableBitmap/BitMapSource if you're trying to create everything uniform. Kind of like here http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/12/how-to-crop-image-using-writeablebitmap.html

Comment: I see. I guess my issue arises with taking up resources while performing the cropping procedure, because my app may potentially have hundreds or thousands of images in its collection. The Viewbox method served as a great way to easily modify the dimensions without image modifications, if only there was a way to do the same but clip parts of the image accordingly. My ultimate goal would be to show squares of the images sized 128x128 in the ListBox for consistency and the user's enjoyment.

Comment: Ah well I should have checked before, but apparently `ViewBox` does support `Clip` Geometry so technically you can recreate a Cropping effect using `Clip` to serve your purpose nicely :)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip(v=vs.95).aspx